# Azure ML webservice columns returned no as expected

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have created an experiment to help categorise a description, this all works fine. However it does not tell me the weightings. When on the studio website I click test on the experiment and call the service I get back a JSON blob including lots of useful data such as the column names and weightings. When I actually use the web service from my app using C# the returned json does not include this information?

Any reason for this?

thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your score module used for the predictive experiment has "append score columns"checked